# Java program to calculates how many different ways you can remove the identical balls from the bag

Tags: java, recursion, math, permutation

In a bag, there are `n` identical balls `(n >= 1)` that needs to be removed from the bag. You can either remove one ball or two balls at a time. Write a code that, given `n`, calculates how many different ways you can remove the balls from the bag.

**Example 1:**

For n = 3, result = 3 *(Diff Ways 1-1, 1-2, 2-1)*

**Example 2:**

For n = 5, result = 8 *(Diff Ways 1-1-1-1-1, 1-1-1-2, 1-1-2-1, 1-2-1-1, 2-1-1-1, 1-2-2, 2-1-2, 2-2-1)*

ways(n) = ways(n-1) + ways(n-2)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Input Number of Balls in a Bag: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfBalls = scanner.nextInt();
        int total = calculateTotalNumberOfWays(numberOfBalls);
        System.out.println("Total Number of ways to remove balls from the bag: " + total);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        throw new InputMismatchException("Only Numbers are accepted for Input of Balls in a Bag");
    }
}

private static int calculateTotalNumberOfWays(int numberOfBalls) {
    switch (numberOfBalls) {
        case 0:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number of Balls in the Bag are 0 cannot remove anything.");
        case 1:
            return 1;
        case 2:
            return 2;
        default:
            return (numberOfBalls - 1) + (numberOfBalls - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have *you* tried?

Comment: I have tried to implement the (n-1) + (n-2) solution. but the problem is if I have 3 balls than total number of ways are 3. If I have 5 balls the total number of ways are 8. so the formula doesn't fit or is not consistent.

Comment: Then show us the code for it so we can fix it

Comment: I have updated the question with the code snippet @THess

Answer (score 4):

Recursive programming is needed to find solution for the problem.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Input Number of Balls in a Bag: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int balls = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Total Number of ways to remove balls from the : " + calculate(balls));
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        throw new InputMismatchException("Only Numbers are accepted for Input of Balls in a Bag");
    }
}

private static int calculate(int balls) {
    switch (balls) {
        case 0:
            return 0;
        case 1:
            return 1;
        case 2:
            return 2;
        default:
            return calculate(balls - 1) + calculate(balls - 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohammed, please can you explain this over a google call or zoom call, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can also take this problem as a fibonacci sequence. You just need to add one more base condition to it. Have a look at the below code snippet. It's written in Java.

```
static int fibRecursion(int  n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else if (n == 2) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return fibRecursion(n - 1) + fibRecursion(n - 2);
    }
}
```